# Functional Analysis, a question that needs further clarification

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C_{0}(a,b) :=\{f \in C(a,b):f(a)=f(b)=0\}$. Show that $C_{0}(a, b)$ is dense in $\bigl(C(a, b); \|.\|_{p}\bigr)$

Comment: What needs to be clarified?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**. To start with, note, that this is obviously wrong for $p = \infty$, as $C_0(a,b)$ is complete in the $\infty$-norm, as uniform convergence preserves continuity and implies pointwise convergence, and hence for $f_n \in C_0(a,b)$ converging uniformly to some $f\in C(a,b)$ we have 
$$ f(a) = \lim_n f_n(a) = 0$$
and the same for $b$.

To see that it holds true for $1 \le p < \infty$, let $f \in C(a,b)$ be arbitrary. Note that $f$ is bounded, by $M$ say. For $n \in \mathbf N$, define 
$$ 
f_n(x) := \begin{cases} 
    f(a+1/n)\cdot n(x-a) & x \in [a,a +1/n]\\
         f(x) & x \in [a+1/n, b-1/n]\\
    f(b-1/n) \cdot n(b-x) & x \in [b-1/n, b]
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $f_n$ is continuous (why?) and show by direct computation (using the boundedness of $f$) that $\|f_n - f\|_p \le 2M\cdot 2^{1/p} \cdot n^{-1/p}$.